# How to create Avro tables using HCatalog REST API before Hive 0.14?

Tags: rest, avro, hcatalog

I couldn't find any docs explain the syntax or grammar for the JSON used by HCatalog REST API.
The office guide ( 
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/WebHCat+Reference+PutTable) only gives a very simple case without saying anything useful about how the JSON part is defined.

I tried the following, but without luck:

```
curl -X PUT -HContent-type:application/json -d '
{  
  "format": {
    "storedAs": "INPUTFORMAT \"org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.avro.AvroContainerInputFormat\" OUTPUTFORMAT \"org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.avro.AvroContainerOutputFormat\"", 
    "rowFormat": { 
      "serde": {
        "name": "org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.avro.AvroSerDe"      
        } } }
  "tblproperties" : [
    "avro.schema.url": "hdfs://xxxx"
  ]
} ' \
'http://<host>:50111/templeton/v1/ddl/database/default/table/table1?user.name=hive'
```

any idea?
Thanks,